# target_blank not working in <a> tag

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, anchor, target

I have a button.when click this go to the particular function.
In the presence onclick target_blank not working.

Any solution

```
   <a onclick="editView('<?php echo $detail->id;?>')" class="btn button_style" title="Edit" target="_blank">Edit</a>
```

**script**

```
   function editView(id)
{
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var input1 = document.createElement("input"); 

    form.action = "<?echo base_url()?>home/editData";
    form.method = "post"

    input1.name = "id";
    input1.type = "hidden";
    input1.value = id;
    form.appendChild(input1);

    document.body.appendChild(form);

    form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`target="_blank"` causes a **link** to open in a new window.

You don't have a link. You have an anchor element with an `onclick` attribute which runs some JavaScript. (You should be using a `<button>` element since you don't have an actual link, [better yet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), have a link to a URL which replicates the effects of the JS server side).

In order to get it to open a new window, you will have to modify your JavaScript (we can't see the `editView` function so it is hard to say precisely how) to make use of [the `open` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

---

You are generating a form which takes no user input and just has fixed data. The easiest way to deal with this is to just us a form in the first place.

```
<form method="post" 
      action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/editData"
      target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $detail->id;?>">
    <button class="btn button_style">Edit</button>
</form>
```

Forget about JavaScript. Add CSS to style the form (e.g. `display: inline; margin: 0; padding: 0`) and button to taste.